# Sorting objects in an array by its values using onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to create **one function** that can be used for 2 `onClick`s to sort objects by `title` and by `genre.name` in this array:

```
const movies = [
  {
    title: "Terminator",
    genre: { _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471818", name: "Action" },
  },
  {
    title: "Rat Race",
    genre: { _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471818", name: "Comedy" },
  },
  {
    title: "Get Out",
    genre: { _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471820", name: "Thriller" },
  },
]
```

So far, for each `onClick` I had to create one function: `onClick={titleSorted}` and `onClick={genreSorted}`. Yet I think this is not a good practice because if I have 10 keys in one object, it'll be too many similar codes in one file.

However, if I create one function *with a parameter* for all `onClick`s:

```
moviesSorted(item) => {}
```

then I can't use `onClick={moviesSorted(title)}` or `onClick={moviesSorted(genre.name)}` because it automatically runs the functions before clicking as I understand.

So please help me find a way for this. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function passed to `onClick` must be a [event handler](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html), implemented as

```
function(event) {
  // ...
}
```

So you in your example, you might want

```
onClick={() => moviesSorted(title)}

// or 

onClick={() => moviesSorted(genre.name)}
```